# How to say "in the lowest time" he/she wakes up?

Tags: time

He wakes up by 6:00 at the earliest" or maybe "at the latest",

I would like to say one wakes up at 6 o clock or after it. how to say this in different forms?

Thanks

Comment: Your first example is perfect. "at the earliest" means that he never wakes up earlier than 6 am... so he may wake up at 7 or 9 but never 5.

Comment: And *at the latest* would mean the exact opposite: that he is never asleep after 6:00.

Comment: Also, "He wakes up no earlier than 6:00" or "He never wakes up before 6:00"  But do you really mean "wakes up"  (becomes conscious of his surroundings and opens his eyes) or do you mean "gets up" (gets out of bed).

Comment: You've answered your own question actually. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

"He wakes up by 6:00 at the earliest" implies that he will not wake up before 6:00. He could wake up anytime after 6:00. If you had used *'latest'*, that would mean that he would get up anytime before 6:00, with 6:00 being the upper limit. If you want to say one wakes up at 6:00 or anytime after 6:00, you could say:

> **"He wakes up by 6:00 at the earliest"** (As you suggested).